# How to move the last x columns of a data frame when the numbers of columns can change

Tags: r, dataframe

This seems like a simple question, but I can't find the solution on here.

I have a data frame with over 900 columns. The precise number of columns can increase over time, but the first 10 are always the same and the last 10 are always the same.

I'd like to move the last 10 columns to just after the first 10, hence they'd occupy positions 11 through 20.

My thought was to use `nrow` to get the total number of columns and use some basic arithmetic:

```
endcol <- df[,ncol(df)]
endcol_start <- endcol-9
midcol_end <- endcol_start-1
```

... to get the index values to re-order.

Then something like:

```
df2 <- df[,c(1:10, endcol_start:endcol, 11:midcol_end)]
```

... to reorder accordingly to the index values set above.

But I just get a vector of column indices without the rows being preserved.

How to preserve the rows in this so the data frame is actually reordered?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `endcol <- ncol(df)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution here uses the dplyr package:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
n <- length(mtcars)
mtcars2 <- select(mtcars, 1:3, (n-2):n, everything())
```

You can see that you've moved the last 3 columns to directly after the first three columns by looking at the names:

```
names(mtcars)
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
names(mtcars2)
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "am"   "gear" "carb" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"
```

You can also do this in base R, but it requires one additional (now that I think of it, trivial) calculation.

```
mtcars3 <- data.frame(mtcars[1:3], mtcars[(n-2):n], mtcars[4:(n-3)])
names(mtcars3)
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "am"   "gear" "carb" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a dplyr solution!  One modification would be :   
 
`select(df, 1:10, (n-9):n, 1:(n-10))`

so that the columns aren't duplicated.

Comment: Use the helpers! Ignoring the repeated columns is built into dplyr. That's what makes it easier than base :)

Comment: I tried your code and I had duplicates. Anyway - got it to work.

Comment: That's very interesting... in the base, double check your parentheses, but if it was in dplyr, I'd be very interested to see the code that produced duplicates (another good thing about dplyr, it's harder to make mistakes with it).

Comment: why not just `mtcars3 <- mtcars[c(1:3,(n-2):n,4:(n-3))]` ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Because then you don't get the error checking that data.frame provides. It's a defensive programming habit.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 21, nrow = 5))


df[,c(1:10, (length(df)-9):length(df), 11:(length(df)-10))]
```

yields

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V11
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in base R

```
#
 test_frame <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(100 * 100, 0, 100), 
                                     nrow = 100,
                                     ncol = 100))
#
# define the columns on left and right to bring together
#  
 left_same_cols <- 10
 right_same_cols <- 10
#  
# populate data so we can visually verify result of move
#  
 test_frame[, 1:10] <- 1
 test_frame[, 90:100] <- 2
#
# define new index sequence
#
 cols <- c(1:left_same_cols, 
            (ncol(test_frame) - right_same_cols):ncol(test_frame), 
            (left_same_cols + right_same_cols):(ncol(test_frame) - 
 right_same_cols))
#
# create new data.frame with desired column order
#  
 test_frame2 <- test_frame[, cols] 
#
```